# Google Script for running a function for the most recent row updated by form edit submission

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using google forms to generate memos for our team. However the  work flow is such that they will need to edit their submission to run subsequent form off the same data. (company IT limitations) This works, but I'm having issues isolating the row that was recently edited by the user. Obviously not a coder and I can't find a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function getFirstEmptyRowByColumnArray() {
  var spr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var column = spr.getRange('A:A');
  var values = column.getValues(); // get all data in one call
  var ct = 0;
  while ( values[ct] && values[ct][0] != "" ) {
    ct++;
  }
  return (ct);
}
```

My intent is to revise the getFirstEmptyRowByColumnArray() function. The code as it currently runs finds the last row, I would need it to find the most recent timestamp in column A and run the autofill function on that row.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!! Just in case anyone else needs to know.

```
function getnewupdate() {
  var spr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var column = spr.getRange('A2:A');
  var values = column.getValues(); // get all data in one call
  var containingValue = max;
  var max = Math.max.apply(null, column.getValues());
  var i = []; 
  for (var y = 0; y < values.length; y++) {
   if(values[y] == containingValue){
      i.push(y);
   }
   return (Number(i)+Number(column.getRow()));
}
}
```